# Windows batch (cmd.exe) command line parameters and string manipulation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, nmake, cl.exe

Let's consider this FOR loop in a Windows batch script:

```
D:\MiLu\Dev\C++\temp :: type string.bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO ECHO %%a
```

It echoess all the arguments, one by one. Really?

```
D:\MiLu\Dev\C++\temp :: string.bat foo.obj bar.obj CPPFLAGS=/EHsc
foo.obj
bar.obj
CPPFLAGS
/EHsc
```

It splits command-line arguments not only on spaces (good), but also on = (not good).
How can I prevent this from happening?

What I want to achieve is simple: A wrapper around NMAKE.exe that specifies `/nologo` to nmake and also - and this is the problem - to the compiler via the environment variables CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS while *at the same time* including any settings for CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS supplied on the command line.

In other words, I want to have the script add `/nologo` to the command line input for CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS even when there is none. Always `/nologo`! Don't annoy me with your logo, comrade compiler!

### Update

Here's what I've come up with based on Mike's answer:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
    SET var1=%%a
    ECHO %%a - !var1! - !var1:~0,1!
    IF "!var1:~0,1!" EQU "/" (
        ECHO gefunden: %%a !var1!
    )
)
```

Going to continue tomorrow ...

### Update 2

Okay, given that tomorrow is already here I might just as well continue ... so here's a working solution, proudly presented. Feel free to comment on how to improve it.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET files=
SET   CFLAGS=/nologo %CFLAGS%
SET CPPFLAGS=/nologo %CPPFLAGS%

SET state=normal
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
    SET curarg=%%a
    REM ECHO %%a - !curarg! - !curarg:~0,1!
    IF /I "%%a" EQU "CFLAGS" (
        SET state=expecting_cflags
    ) ELSE IF /I "%%a" EQU "CPPFLAGS" (
        SET state=expecting_cppflags
    ) ELSE (
        IF "!curarg:~0,1!" EQU "/" (
            REM ECHO gefunden: %%a !curarg!
            IF "!state!" EQU "expecting_cflags" (
                REM ECHO expecting_cflags
                SET CFLAGS=!CFLAGS! !curarg!
            ) ELSE IF "!state!" EQU "expecting_cppflags" (
                REM ECHO expecting_cppflags
                SET CPPFLAGS=!CPPFLAGS! !curarg!
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO Logikfehler >&2
            )
        ) ELSE (
            SET files=!files! !curarg!
        )
        SET state=normal
    )
)
ECHO Dateien:  !files! >&2
ECHO CFLAGS:   !CFLAGS! >&2
ECHO CPPFLAGS: !CPPFLAGS! >&2
:: ECHO ON
nmake /nologo %files% CFLAGS="%CFLAGS%" CPPFLAGS="%CPPFLAGS%"
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: The standard delimiters for Batch file parameters and FOR sets are comma, semicolon and equal-sign, besides spaces.

Comment: Thanks, @Aacini. Here's a [useful example page at SS64.COM](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). Doesn't look like there's a way to override the delimiters of the simple FOR loop (without `/F`), does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around the problem would be to specify "CPPFLAGS=/EHsc" and then in the loop use %%~a to get rid of the double quotes.

Another way to work around the problem would be to check the first character of %%a, and if it is a `/` then prepend a `=` to it.  In order to achieve this you will need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, assign %%a to a variable, and then use the %variable:~1,1% notation to extract the first character so you can compare it against `/`.  For more information about this notation, type `help set`.

**Update** (after OP's update)

The following fragment appears to work, it is a bit simpler than the corresponding fragment in your solution, and it does not contain any hard-coded names of the arguments, so it is more general-purpose:

```
SET allargs=
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
    SET curarg=%%a
    IF "!curarg:~0,1!" EQU "/" (
        SET allargs=!allargs!=!curarg!
    ) ELSE (
        SET allargs=!allargs! !curarg!
    )
)
ECHO !allargs!
```

Comment: Thanks, halfway there. Going to update my question with what I've achieved so far.

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion for an improvement on what you have come up with.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Unfortunately, I don't understand your improvement. It appears to simply reproduce the original `%*`. I'd need a way to merge in my default options, originally `/nologo`, but `/W4` is useful as well. I can supply `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` only once. So how would I merge in my defaults with your solution?

Comment: Okay, I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do.  I thought the only problem was that you did not want to lose the '=' sign. Apparently you want to do something more complex than that: in the command-line of the batch-file you are trying to combine parameters to CL as well as parameters to the batch file itself.  So, scratch my update. Your solution is fine.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. Giving you the final vote as you provided the clue to solving this. Man, that batch scripting is difficult! All those cryptic `% ! %% :~`. (Same story with Bash, nearly impossible to remember that stuff.)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the complexity of these things is insane, and it is all in the name of not having to enclose strings in quotes. Sometimes I think it is not worth the hassle, twisting these shell languages to get them to do what you want, and it is better to just write the program in a real language.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
string.bat foo.obj bar.obj "CPPFLAGS=/EHsc"
```

If you're appending the `CPPFLAGS` argument yourself, try enclosing it in quotes.

Reference: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Comment: Yes, I had tried enclosing `CPPFLAGS=/EHsc` in double quotes, and it does work. I didn't consider it convenient, though. Useful link, by the way. [Here's another one.](http://www.dostips.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for /f` in a loop to force splitting argument list by space and not by equal sign. Try something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set params=%*

:loop
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%A in ('!params!') do (
  echo %%A
  set params=%%B
)
if not "!params!"=="" goto loop

endlocal
```

Comment: Works nicely, thanks! Had tried this approach, but on the parameter list directly (`%*`), not on a variable. And that didn't work nicely. Sort of counter-intuitive: you assign the parameter to a variable, and the behaviour changes completely. Okay, guess that's because `%*` is a list beast.

Comment: I used `for /f` because it allows to declare the character I want to split the string by (by default it is a space, and only space - no equal sign). But `for /f` is for iterating through lines and splitting them into fields, so I had to add external loop and reformat the input string each time - that's why I used the variable. In this case `for` is just a string operation: "put the string up to the first space in %%A and the rest in %%B" - no looping.